# How to delete cached element manually in Play Framework 2.3.X?

Tags: caching, playframework-2.3

I have my web application using Play 2.3.3. Here is a method in my controller :

```
@Cached(key = "categories", duration = 3600)
public static Result index() throws ApiException {
    // Stuff read from database here
    return ok(MyView.render(data));
}
```

My question is how can I delete the `categories` element from the cache manually to force it to be regenerated ? For example, when I add a category in my database, I don't want to wait for the cache to expire to make it visible to my users.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation : https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaCache

So is the cache stored in RAM, somewhere in the filesystem ?
Thanks.

**EDIT** : Ideally, I'd like to connect to my server, browse to a directory and delete the file. I suppose that's not possible with EHCache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `Cache.remove(key)` from the docs you have linked.

```
 import play.api.cache.Cache

 Cache.remove("categories")
```

Play uses EhCache by default, which is an in-memory cache really only suited for single machine deployments. You can replace it another cache plugin though, [play2 memcached](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question, ideally I'd like to delete directly from the server. But if you're saying that it's in-memory, I suppose that's not possible.

Comment: @Chafik Nope, not possible that way. There's no way to even retrieve a list of cached keys programatically. You could accomplish something like that using a redis server and plugin.